# unit testing directive, tests not returning value

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Hello I am looking to test a directive but I am having a hell of a time doing it. 
this is my test so far:

```
describe('pbImagePicker', function () {

    beforeEach(module('pb.campaigns.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var $compile;
    var element;
    var $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$document_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $document = _$document_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));

    describe('template', function () {




        it('should render HTML based on scope correctly', function () {
            scope.campaign = {
                fileId: '43253',
                accountId: '3874',
                imageSource: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon',
                width: '250',
                height: '250'
            };

            var element = $compile('<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />')(scope);
            scope.$digest();

            expect(element.html()).toEqual('<img data-ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon" width="250" height="250" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />');
            //expect(element.attr('src')).toBe('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon');
        });

    });


    describe('element.click()', function () {

        var campaign = {
            fileId: '43253',
            accountId: '3874',
            imageSource: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon',
            width: '250',
            height: '250'
        };
        var image = {
            storageUrl: 'http://www.pressboard.com/avatar/7453',
            fileId: 6432342
        };
        var accountId = 543222;
        var pickImage = function (accountId) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.resolve(image);
            return defer.promise;
        };

        //beforeEach(function () {
        //    element = angular.element('<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />');
        //    compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
        //    compiled.triggerHandler('click');
        //});

        it('should resolve a promise when clicked', function () {
            scope.campaign = campaign;
            scope.accountId = accountId;
            scope.pickImage = pickImage;

            element = angular.element('<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />');
            compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
            compiled.triggerHandler('click');

            spyOn(scope, 'pickImage');
            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.pickImage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(scope.accountId);
        });

        it('should assign data from resolved promise when clicked', function () {
            scope.campaign = campaign;
            scope.accountId = accountId;
            scope.pickImage = pickImage;

            element = angular.element('<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />');
            compiled = $compile(element)(scope);
            compiled.triggerHandler('click');

            scope.$digest();
            expect(scope.imageSource).toEqual('http://www.pressboard.com/avatar/7453');
            expect(scope.fileId).toEqual(6432342);
        });


    });

});
```

this is the directive I am testing:

```
angular.module('pb.campaigns.directives')
    .directive('pbImagePicker', ['$window', '$document', function ($window, $document) {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: '<img data-ng-src="{{ imageSource }}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />',
            scope: {
                fileId: '=pbFileId',
                accountId: '=pbAccountId',
                defaultSrc: '@pbDefaultSrc',
                width: '@pbWidth',
                height: '@pbHeight'
            },
            controller: 'pbImagePickerController',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('defaultSrc', function (value) {
                    if (value !== undefined) {
                        scope.imageSource = value;
                    }
                });

                element.click(function () {
                    scope.pickImage(scope.accountId).then(function (image) {
                        scope.imageSource = image.storageUrl;
                        scope.fileId = image.fileId;
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The errors that I am getting are:

```
Test 'pbImagePicker template:should render HTML based on scope correctly' failed
    Expected '' to equal '<img data-ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon" width="250" height="250" alt="Image Picker" class="img-rounded" />'.

Test 'pbImagePicker element.click():should resolve a promise when clicked' failed
    Expected spy pickImage to have been called with [ 543222 ] but it was never called.

Test 'pbImagePicker element.click():should assign data from resolved promise when clicked' failed
    Expected undefined to equal 'http://www.pressboard.com/avatar/7453'.
```

I am really stuck for how to proceed or if im on the right track. The angular docs for testing directives are a little lacking. http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/01/27/5-tricks-about-directives-and-tests/ was a big help getting started if anyone else is having problems getting started.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of errors... I'm gonna explain using your first unit test : describe('template')

when you compile your element, you set the attributes "width" to {{width}} instead of {{campaign.width}} (based on your scope definition) and so on...

if you want to test your directive, you should test for the attributes and class instead of element.html() because the template is an `<img/>` tag

**Update**
made a few modifications to the directive's definition:

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
angular.module('pb.campaigns.directives', [])

.directive('pbImagePicker', ['$q', function ($q) {

  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace : 'true',
    scope: {
        fileId: '=pbFileId',
        accountId: '=pbAccountId',
        defaultSrc: '@pbDefaultSrc',
        width: '@pbWidth',
        height: '@pbHeight'
    },
    template: '<img ' +
      'data-ng-src="{{imageSource }}" '+
      'alt="Image Picker" ' +
      'width="{{width}}" ng-click="clickFn(imageSource, fileId)" '+
      'height="{{height}}"/>',
    //controller: 'pbImagePickerController',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch('defaultSrc', function (value) {
            if (value !== undefined) {
                scope.imageSource = value;
            }
        });

        element.addClass('img-rounded');

        function pickImage() {
           var image = {
                storageUrl: 'http://www.pressboard.com/avatar/7453',
                fileId: 6432342
            };
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(image);
            return deferred.promise;
       }
       scope.clickFn = function () {
           pickImage()
             .then(function (image) {

                 // we encounter a non-assign error on scope.fileId
                 // due to isolated scope assignment
                 // Expression '{0}' used with directive '{1}' is non-assignable!
                 //https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign
                 scope.imageSource = image.storageUrl; 
                 //scope.fileId = image.fileId;
              }, function () {
                console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
              });

       };
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Specs testing** full tests for template and click event

```
//------- SPECS - TESTING -------------
describe('pb.campaigns.directives', function () {

    var $compile,
        elem,
        element,
        $rootScope,
        $scope;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('pb.campaigns.directives');

        inject(function ($q, _$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$controller_, _$document_) {

            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();


            scope.campaign = {
              fileId: '43253',
              accountId: '3874',
              imageSource: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/12345?s=40&d=identicon',
              width: '250',
              height: '250'
            };

            element = angular.element(
                '<pb-image-picker '+
                'file-id="campaign.fileId" ' +
                'account-id="campaign.accountId" ' +
                'pb-default-src="{{campaign.imageSource}}" ' +
                'pb-width="{{campaign.width}}" ' +
                'pb-height="{{campaign.height}}">' +
                '<pb-image-picker/>'
            );
            _$compile_(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest(); 
        });
    });


    describe('template', function () {

        it('should render HTML based on scope correctly', function () {          
            scope.imageSource = scope.campaign.imageSource;            
            expect(scope.imageSource).toMatch(scope.defaultSrc);
            expect(element.attr('data-ng-src')).toEqual(scope.imageSource);
            expect(element.hasClass('img-rounded')).toBe(true);
            expect(element.attr('alt')).toMatch('Image Picker');
            expect(element.attr('width')).toEqual('250');
            expect(element.attr('height')).toEqual('250'); 
        });
    });


    describe('element click', function () {

        beforeEach (inject(function($q) {
            $scope = element.isolateScope();
            $scope.$apply();
            spyOn($scope, 'clickFn').andCallThrough();
            element.triggerHandler('click');
       }));

        afterEach(function(){
            $scope.$apply();
        });

        it('should resolve a promise when clicked', function () {
            expect($scope.clickFn).toBeDefined();
            expect($scope.clickFn).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });

        it('should assign data from resolved promise when clicked', function () {
            expect($scope.imageSource)
              .toEqual('http://www.pressboard.com/avatar/7453');
           // expect($scope.fileId).toEqual(6432342);
        }); 

    });
});
```

NOTE : As it was pointed out by tasseKat the first post wasn't the right way to test a directive (sorry about that). Rather, it was an attempt to show you what to write inside the `it()` function. hopefully this version is a better example.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/zgjL5wg0/) to demonstrate (and for you to play with)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the way to test a directive. This test is compiling the template that is used, it's not even using the directive that you should be testing. You can basically remove the directive and the test would still pass.

Comment: yes, the element attributes (width, height etc.) should have been defined in le `link` function of the directive and the ` element` should have been `$compile(<pb-image-picker></pb-image-picker>)(scope)` . I was pointing out what to put within the `it` function. I should probably put a full solution. you're welcome to put a better solution, I'm always eager to learn :)

Comment: @tasseKATT I've edited my previous answer. It would be great if you could review it, just to be sure. thanks

Comment: I will take a look at it a little later :)